# Change the version of default style.css in wordpress

Tags: css, jquery, javascript, wordpress-version

I'm working on [Wordpress + Bootstrap 4](https://afterimagedesigns.com/wp-bootstrap-starter/?dashboard=1) by customising according to the design. The default style.css loads as:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-bootstrap-starter-style-css'  href='http://localhost/hrone/wp-content/themes/theme_name/style.css?ver=5.2.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I would like to change the version from 5.2.3 to 5.2.4 or auto change it time base. How do I go about doing this? I have just 1 css file since this is a custom theme.

Answer (score 1):

It's using `5.2.3` because no version was specified when `style.css` was enqueued/registered. So it fell back to the version of WordPress.

If you pass in a version when calling `wp_enqueue_style`, it will use that value instead

Comment: `wp_enqueue_style' creates a new css file which isn't what I want.

Comment: You theme already calls `wp_enqueue_style()` somewhere. You need to specify the version wherever that is. It appears to be line 80 of functions.php in the latest version.

Comment: I have this in line 80 `function wp_boostrap_starter_add_editor_styles() {
        add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'wp_boostrap_starter_add_editor_styles' );` which isn't the style.css but the custom css file. I'm working on style.css.

Comment: @ElaineByene `wp_enqueue_style` does not create new files, and it is `style.css` because it says so in the HTML of your question, it'll be enqueued as `bootstrap-starter-style` judging from the id attribute

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php file (you're using a custom child theme, right?) change/add the version parameter to `wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' )` this will pull the version number from your theme's style.css file.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Setting this parameter to false will use the WordPress version.

wp_get_theme() returns the theme object for the current theme which contains the version. 
wp_get_theme()->parent()->get( 'Version' ) will return the parent themes version.

```
$parent_style = 'wp-bootstrap-starter';
wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, wp_get_theme()->parent()->get( 'Version' ) );

wp_enqueue_style(
    'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the version number in your style.css file.

Edit: I misunderstood. I think that's the WordPress version.

Comment: That’s not where this number comes from.